# How to remove the button with class addNewRestaurant from all the section

Tags: jquery

This is my HTML

```
<div id="restmenu" class="restMenu">

   <ul>

      <section id="office" class="ulseWrap lielement">
         <div class="intit">office<span class="inDelete"></span></div>
         <ul class="restListings">
            <div class="inner-intit">
               <sub class="sub">Your Favorite Restaurant</sub><br>
               <li>
                  <h6>Attapur</h6>
                  <p>Near Pullareddy sweets, Mehdipatna,</p>
                  <span class="inDelete inDeleteSub"></span>
               </li>
            </div>
            <input type="button" location="home" name="btn1" class="btn btn-success addNewRestaurant" value="home">
         </ul>
      </section>

      <section id="home" class="ulseWrap lielement">
         <div class="intit">home<span class="inDelete"></span></div>
         <ul class="restListings">
            <div class="inner-intit">
               <sub class="sub">Your Favorite Restaurant</sub><br>
               <li>
                  <h6>Nizampet</h6>
                  <p>Near GRIET, Nizamet</p>
                  <span class="inDelete inDeleteSub"></span>
               </li>
            </div>
            <input type="button" location="home" name="btn1" class="btn btn-success addNewRestaurant" value="home">
         </ul>
      </section>

      <section id="hostel" class="ulseWrap lielement">
         <div class="intit">hostel<span class="inDelete"></span></div>
      </section>

   </ul>
</div>
```

I need to remove the button with class addNewRestaurant  from all the  section

I tried with different options but nothing worked .

```
$("#restmenu").find('.addNewRestaurant').remove();
```

could anybody please help me .

forgot to add

the button is created this way

```
  var $newbutton= $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'button', location:locationname , name:'btn1', class:'btn btn-success addNewRestaurant', value:locationname});
```

Comment: Did you wrap you code with `$(document).ready`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove it, do this. If you want to just hide it call hide. The main thing to do is to check that the DOM has loaded by wrapping it in `$(function() { });`

```
$(function() {
    $('#restmenu .addNewRestaurant').remove();
});
```

I have created a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jzd5kxuu/1/

Comment: can't i remove that completely rather than hiding .

Comment: `$("#restmenu .addNewRestaurant")` selector will be more correct.

Comment: I wrappped the code inside the function ,but still no luck .

Comment: @PreethiJain well, it's a suprise... I have already voted up for this answer. It works in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bzd4dypu/), doesn't it?

Comment: The button is created dynamically this way var $newbutton= $('<input/>').attr(

Comment: @PreethiJain then it is appended to html, and then should be removed?

Comment: @PreethiJain I [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bzd4dypu/1/) and it still works. Maybe I don't understand what you're talking about...

Comment: I have updated the fiddle to show you it adding and deleting - it is a simple example - but shows you the concept: http://jsfiddle.net/jzd5kxuu/3/